# How can I make everything else hidden when I am at a certain part of a website (id link)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not really sure how to word this. I'm trying to make it so that when the user clicks a button, everything on a webpage is hidden except for part of it.

Currently, I have something like this

```js
function changeDisplay(){
document.getElementById("first").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("second").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.active {display: block;}
.inactive {display: none;}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="active"> original content </div>
<div id="second" class="inactive"> different content here </div>
<a href="#second" onclick="changeDisplay()">link</a>
```

When you click the button, the text disappears and is replaced by something else.
Notice that I used a link to an id. I reference [this card (I always reference this one)](https://f01b1b5abda7a8f1.demo.carrd.co/#about). When you click About, for example, the website changes to `https://..../#about`.

When you reload the site, it displays the about page, instead of the home page. However, with my solution (JS to style display), it doesn't work -- if you reload the page, you'll be shown the first div, even if the url is linked to `.../#second`.

So how could I make the website display the second div only (like after clicking the link) when I reload (when the url has `../#second` in it)?

I'd prefer an answer using just HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the hash via `location.hash` and perform checks like so:

```js
function changeDisplay() {
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "block";
}
location.hash = "#second"; //<-- debugging purposes only, do not include on your site

if(location.hash=="#second"){
  changeDisplay();
}
```

```css
.active {
  display: block;
}

.inactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="active"> original content </div>
<div id="second" class="inactive"> different content here </div>
<a href="#second" onclick="changeDisplay()">link</a>
```